# Cisco 891F - is that a router or a switch in?

Tags: cisco

Cisco 891F - is that a router or a switch  ??
Cisco 891F - is that a router or a switch  ??

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Cisco 891F is an Integrated Services Router for Enterprise remote offices with up to 50 users.

It has a build in 8-port 10-/100-/1000-Mbps managed switch (4‑ports PoE capable with 125W power supply adapter).

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/routers/c891f-integrated-services-routers/model.html#~tab-documents